# Needing to count record if it shows up on 2nd sheet, but only want to count once

Tags: google-sheets, unique, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, countif

I have an entire list of all the events (Sheet 2) and a specific list of events (Sheet 1) I need to know if the event is on sheet 2 counts it once using a formula on (sheet 1; column K) - no matter how many times it appears.

Specific Events on Sheet 1 Column A:A, Entire Events on Sheet 2 Events!,A:A

Column A (Sheet 1)
Event 03521,
Event 03338,

Column L (Sheet 2)
Event 03521,
Event 03338,
Event 03521,

I want to return on Column K (Sheet 1) 
                  
Sheet 1 A2: Event 03521

Sheet 1 K2: Count (1)

I tried =CountA(UNIQUE(Event!L:L, A2)) and I get a 1 all the way down, which I know is not correct. Some have 225 appearances, some have 0.

This is a 2nd part of the issue, some times the event name in Sheet 2 is just the number 3521. Not sure if I can look at both "Event 03521 and or 03521, or 3521. I may just try to search each 3521 and add Event 03521 to it to fix this issue.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IF(A:A="",,IF(ISNUMBER(A:A*1), "Event "&TEXT(A:A, "00000"), A:A)), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col1)''"))
```

[image]